# How to select an id when we do not have matching records in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Say i have two tables like below:

```
+-------------------------+   +-------------------------+
| Person                  |   | Person Details          |
+----------+--------------+   +-------------------------+
| Name     |VARCHAR(255)  |   | SK       | Decimal(18,0)|
| PersonID | INT(11)      |   | PersonID | INT(11)      |
+----------+--------------+   | Name     | VARCHAR(255) |
                              |                         |
                              +----------+--------------+
```

My tables contain following data:

```
+------------------------+    +---------------------------+
| Person                 |    | Person Details            |
+----------+-------------+    +-------+----------+--------+
| Name     | PersonID    |    | SK    | PersonID | Name   |
+----------+-------------+    +-------+----------+--------+
| Sean     | 1           |    | 1     | 1        | Sean   |
| Javier   | 1           |    | 2     | 1        | Cooper |
| Fluffy   | 2           |    | 3     | 2        | Trade  |
+----------+-------------+    +-------+----------+--------+
```

I need to select PersonId from Person table where all Name associated with an Id should not be in Person Details table. In above example my query should return only 2 not PersonID 1 as "Sean" is found in both Person and Person_details table. I tried below query and did not work:

```
sel P.PersonID
from Person P
left join Person_details PD
on PD.PersonId = P.PersonId
and PD.Name = P.Name

where PD.PersonId is NULL
```

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query returns all PersonIDs where *any* name is missing.

To get those IDs where *all* names are missing you need aggregation:

```
SELECT P.PersonID
FROM Person P
LEFT JOIN Person_details PD
  ON PD.PersonId = P.PersonId
 AND PD.Name = P.Name
GROUP BY p.PersonID             -- for each PersonID
HAVING Max(pd.PersonID) IS NULL -- no match was found
```